# How i can update lats item listView(android)

Tags: java, android, listview

Sorry for my english. In Android SDK have somthing method who change padding or margin lats item in listView? I try search somthing in google but i cant find enithing.

Comment: have youread about adapter ? See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Comment: do you want to apply margin at bottom of listview ?

Comment: @sanatshukla i want add margin to lats item in listView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your getView() method check for last item first:

```
if (position == getCount() - 1)
```

to get the last item.

Then you can set padding on your view using setPadding() method or call getLayoutParams() on your view and call setMargins() on the params.

Be sure your view already has layout params and does not return null, else you need to create and set layout params on your view.